# reg exp to find a sub sequence of a word in a line

Tags: regex

there are many reg exp to find a word in a line, but i am stuck figuring out how to find a reg exp that gives me a sub string of a word in a line.

EX: #if (! ( ((defined COA_MODEL)||(defined DIA_MODEL)) && (CFG_STATISTICAL_DATA)) )

I need find if this line has _MODEL/_model only if line starts with '#if' and has '!' , how could i do it?

I tried with ^#if(.*?(\b_MODEL\b)[^$]*)$ and no success.

thanks and regards
Rajath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as per your criteria:

http://regexr.com?321fs

`^#if(.*?(\w+_MODEL\b)[^$]*)$`

Comment: ah ok i missed \w 
thnak you.. it matches the whole line with all these requirements.
But what would changes i need to do if i have to select _model and not the whole line itself.
Thanks
Rajath

Comment: sorry forgot one more thing. Along with this '!' should also be available anywhere in the line. Is it it possible to do it in the same reg exp. Thanks